# I'm failing to update multiple data in my modelset at once

Tags: django-forms

I have pre-populated my table with products data which I then retrieve to edit. I am trying to edit several rows then save it at one go.

I have two models of Grade and Product described below

```
class Grade(models.Model): 
    GRADE_TYPES = (
        ("p", "Primary Grade"),
        ("S", "Secondary Grade"),
    )
    grade_name = models.TextField(max_length=10, unique = True)
    grade_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GRADE_TYPES)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['grade_name']

def __str__(self):
    return self.grade_name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('grade_list')


class Product(models.Model): 
    production_date = models.DateField()
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    kilos = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits = 5)
    products=[]

class Meta:
    unique_together =('production_date','grade')
    ordering = ['-production_date']


def __str__(self):
    return self.production_date

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('production_list')
```

My form

```
class Add_ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    product_date = datetime.today()-timedelta(days=1)
    grades = Grade.objects.all()   
    for grade in grades:
        product = Product.create(product_date,grade,0)
        product.save()

class Add_product(View):     
    template_name =  'create_daily_product.html'     
    Product_Formset = modelformset_factory(Product, form=Add_ProductForm)

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        context ={
            'product_form':self.Product_Formset(queryset = 
             Product.objects.filter(kilos=0.0)),
        }
        return render(request,self.template_name,context) 

    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_formset = self.Product_Formset(self.request.POST)
        if product_formset.is_valid:
            for products in product_formset:
                products.save() # The Product could not be changed because 
                the data didn't validate.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("success.url"))                    
        else:
            context ={
                'product_form':self.Product_Formset(),
            }
            return render(request,'create_daily_product.html',context)
```

I populate the model Product with initial data and then retrieve it so that I can change the quantities of kilos to other values. I then edit the kilos successfully but on clicking update to save, I get the error message "The Product could not be changed because the data didn't validate". The form appears to be valid but on starting to save it fails.

I should render the data to edit, update it and then save it. The first two happen successfully, but not the last. I also want to only save the rows where the kilos>0, but cannot test that since the saving fails.

Answer (score 0):

it probably because this line
`if product_formset.is_valid:`

it supposed to be 
`if product_formset.is_valid():`

also, check the indentation for functions in your model and modelform.
your models should be

```
class Grade(models.Model): 
    GRADE_TYPES = (
        ("p", "Primary Grade"),
        ("S", "Secondary Grade"),
    )
    grade_name = models.TextField(max_length=10, unique = True)
    grade_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GRADE_TYPES)

    class Meta:
       ordering = ['grade_name']

    def __str__(self):
       return self.grade_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('grade_list')


class Product(models.Model): 
    production_date = models.DateField()
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    kilos = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits = 5)
    products=[]

    class Meta:
       unique_together =('production_date','grade')
       ordering = ['-production_date']


    def __str__(self):
       return self.production_date

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('production_list')
```

while your modelform:

```
class Add_ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       ......
```

Comment: Thanks for identifying the missing (), it has taken away the error. But I am still not able to save. The form is not valid and yet I can see all the data when I raise a validation error in the else statement.

Comment: have you debug it? `product_formset.errors` will give you reasons why your formset is invalid